# AJAX, POST returning Method not allowed

Tags: python, ajax, api

For the life of me, I've been looking at this for hours and comparing it to what DOES work and can't figure out what's wrong.

In an HTML page I have the following:

```
        function passArrayToAJAX(user){
            // this function is to take the user details and pass them using AJAX
            console.log(user)
            $.ajax({
                "url":"http://127.0.0.1:5000/addUser",
                "method":"POST",
                "data":JSON.stringify(user),
                "dataType":"json",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "success":function(result){
                    // message box code from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp
                    alert("New user added");
                    window.location.replace('/clients')
                },
                "error":function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log("Error: " + status + " Message: " + error)
                }
            })
        }
```

... and in the server (python) I have:

```
# add a user
@app.route('/addUser/<uuid:user>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def addUser(user):
    try:
        logging.info('started to add user')
        content=request.get_json(force=True)
        username=content.get('username')
        pwd=content.get('password')
        county=content.get('county')
        result=daoDV.addUser(username,pwd,county)
        logging.info('User added: ' + result)
        return jsonify(result)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error adding User: ' + str(e))
        return jsonify('User not added')
```

but it's returning :
[image]

Many thanks

Seamus

Comment: What web framework are you using? Flask? Also, you might want to remove the user ID from the URL of an add-method. The URL you are POSTing to in your JS code is not the same as the one defined in your `addUser` method

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot to mention it is Flask. The URL is different? IP address is the localhost 127.0.0.1 port 5000. I haven't included that in any of the methods and they work (including another POST).